# Is it possible to nest a .Net Core web app under an older .Net web app and share the forms auth on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to run a new **dnx46** / **dnxcore50** (*frameworks referenced due to changing names*) web app as a child of an existing web app running on **.net451** on IIS.

I am wondering if this is first possible considering the large difference in frameworks and secondly, if it is possible, sharing the forms authentication on the child app from the parent app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing auth tickets requires a bunch of work which isn't well documented and exists mostly as samples. You'd have to update your membership schema on your 4.5 app to Identity 3.0 and then plug in a new forms authentication ticket formatter so your 4.5 app is issuing tickets in the Core format. Finally you'd need to share a directory, or configure core to store your encryption keys in the same place as Core looks for them.

I'd wait for RC2 before even attempting this as the migration / sharing path should be documented by then.